# Prepopulate Visualforce text box

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to 'prepopulate' (when the page loads) a visual force textbox:

```
 <apex:page controller="FedExLabelOverviewController">
   <apex:form >
     <apex:inputText ... />
   </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

with a string value from an apex class (i.e. test.getValue();)

I was wondering how this was done. Can I reference the other class' variable in the controller class of the visualforce page?

Edit:  I am using inputText because my intention is to be able to clear the text box when the user wants to type something in.  Essentially, I want to set the default value on the input text box.

Comment: use html pass through and `html-placeholder="your default text"`

Comment: @JesseMilburn Why dont you add that as an answer .I think that qualifies as answer :)

Comment: @JesseMilburn I don't want help text/placeholder, per se, but I do want to populate the field with actual text.  If the field was read by a class, it would return the prepopulated text.

Comment: In that scenario. `<apex:inputText value="{!value}"/>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use html pass through in your visualforce markup

```
<apex:inputText html-placeholder="your default text"/>
```